# FPDF error: some data has already been output. Can't send PDF file

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm using FPDF library to generate PDF document, but I'm getting error **"Some data has already been output, can't send PDF"**.

```
<?php
function fetch_data()
{
    //užklausa
    include('database_connection.php');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM mvap.daiktas";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $id = 1;
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $pavadinimas = $row['daiktoPavadinimas'];
        $inventorinis = $row['inventorinisNr'];
    }
    $data = '2020-01-25';
    $html = '
    <body>
        <style>
            th {font-weight: bold; font-family:  };
            tr {font-weight: normal};
        </style>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" style="text-align: center">
            <tr>
                <th width="30px" height="5">Eil. Nr.</th>
                <th width="130px" height="5">Materialinės vertybės pavadinimas</th>
                <th width="80px" height="5">Inventorinis numeris</th>
                <th width="100px" height="5">Gamyklinis numeris</th>
                <th width="70" height="5">Gavimo data</th>
                <th width="65" height="5">Gavėjo parašas</th>
                <th width="70" height="5">Grąžinimo data</th>
                <th width="80" height="5">Grąžinančio asmens parašas</th>
                <th width="70" height="5">Priimančio asmens parašas</th>
                <th width="80" height="5">Pastabos</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>'. $id .'</td>
                <td>'. $pavadinimas .'</td>
                <td>'. $inventorinis .'</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>'. $data .'</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </body>

    ';
    return $html;
}
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    require('libs/TCPDF/tcpdf_import.php');
    $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Apskaitos kortelė");
    $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
    $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
    $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('dejavuserif');
    $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
    $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '10', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);
    $obj_pdf->SetFont('dejavuserif', '', 10);
    $obj_pdf->AddPage();
    $obj_pdf->Cell(0,6,'ĮMONĖ',0,0,'C');
    $obj_pdf->Ln();
    $obj_pdf->SetLineWidth(0.5);
    $obj_pdf->Line(5, 15, 297-5, 15);
    $obj_pdf->Ln();
    $obj_pdf->SetFontSize(12);
    $obj_pdf->Cell(0,20,'KOMPIUTERINĖS TECHNIKOS, RYŠIO PRIEMONIŲ IR PROGRAMINĖS ĮRANGOS APSKAITOS KORTELĖ',0,0,'C');
    $obj_pdf->Ln();
    $obj_pdf->SetFontSize(10);
    $obj_pdf->Cell(20, 40, 'Valdybos, skyriaus pavadinimas' , 0, false, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    $obj_pdf->Cell(230, 40, 'SKOV NKC', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    $obj_pdf->Line(10, 65, 297-100, 65);
    $obj_pdf->Ln(0);
    $obj_pdf->Cell(20, 55, 'Turto buvimo vieta, kab. Nr.' , 0, false, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    $obj_pdf->Cell(230, 55, 'Kabinetas', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    $obj_pdf->Line(10, 72, 297-100, 72);
    $obj_pdf->Ln(0);
    $obj_pdf->Cell(20, 70, 'Atsakingo žmogaus vardas, pavardė' , 0, false, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    $obj_pdf->Cell(230, 70, 'Vardenis Pavardenis', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    $obj_pdf->Line(10, 80, 297-100, 80);
    $content = '';
    $content .= fetch_data();
    $obj_pdf->SetXY(5, 90);
    $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);
    $obj_pdf->Output('doc.pdf', 'I');
}
?>
```

I tried to add **"ob_start()"** at the beggining and **"ob_end_flush()"** at the end. I know that it's not first topic of this problem, but tried to find information in this forum and now I have no idea what to do more. I hope somebody could help me to fix this problem.

Comment: That output should be seen in the browser (dev console).. probably an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem. I won't delete my topic. Hope this will help for someone.
Solved problem by posting this php code to another blank php file and called that file from another file button click. Now it works without problem.

Comment: maybe an UTF-8 BOM in the old file?

Comment: I don't know. It's declared like this: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> because this file also contains html code.

Comment: The BOM is "invisible" (unprintable characters).. any decent text editor will tell you the encoding of the file.

Comment: I've been stuck on this for some time. This worked. Thankyou!